# horizontal line at top of my site needs to be fixed in the header

Tags: css, html

I have a horizontalm line seperating my header from the body content and would like it to stay in place when scrolling. When i try to set it to 'fixed' position, it does something funny, can someone kindly help, thanks.

Here is the HTML

```
     <div id="wrapperfull">

     <div class="fitter">

     <div id="head">

     <div id="header">
     <a href="index.html"><img src="../Images/Header2.png" width="379" height="99" alt="Just Joel Header"></a>
     </div><!-- end header div -->

     <div class="navigation">

     <div class="menu-holder">

     <ul class="menu">

        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>

        <li><a href='print.html'>WORK</a>
      </li>

        <li><a href="photography.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
      </li>

        <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
      </li>

        <li><a href="inspired.html">INSPIRED</a>
      </li>

       </ul>
     </div>
     <!-- menu-holder end -->
     </div><!-- end navigation div -->     


     </div>


     </div>

     <div class="bottom-color">
     </div>

     <div class="heading">

     <h1>SHOWCASE</h1>

     </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
    #wrapperfull {
min-height: 100%;
width: 1050px;
border: thin;
border-color: #00BDE5;
margin-top: 0px;
background-color: #FFF;
position: relative; /* for the absolute positioned footer */
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
padding-top: 0.1px;
padding-right: 40px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 30px;
    }

    .fitter {
height: 115px;
width: 1050px;
background-color: #FFF;
    }

    .bottom-color {
height: 15px;
color: #00BDE5;
border-style:solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #head {
    height: 100px;
    width: 1070px;
    border: none;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    }

    #header {
height: 125px;
width: 1050px;
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
position: fixed;
background-color: #FFF;
margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .navigation {
height: 75px;
width: px;
float: left;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
padding-top: 20px;
font-family: "geogtq sb";
position: fixed;
background-color: #FFF;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should to improve it and leave a skyblue line fixed below your navigation, delete

```
  <div class="bottom-color"> </div>
```

and replace it with a border bottom of *#header* or *#head* (I found that one of them is unnecessary).

you could refactor a little and simplify your use of divs.

Also maybe review your html and CSS looking for bugs like;

```
width: px;
```

on line 54

Comment: Do you think there are a few that could go and are redundant inside the fitter div?

Comment: @user3015137 yes, if you want that line to stay fixed the best approach is to use a border-bottom in the header container, IMO

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your code and if i understand correctly what your saying then it seems to work for me. look at this code.

```
its also a good idea to add 
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

http://jsfiddle.net/4gHuT/2/
```

Comment: The line stays where it is and doesn't go behind the header?